# Real solution of Riccati type equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I want a real solution of the inequality 
\begin{equation}
X P X^t \le Q
\end{equation}
where $P$ and $Q$ are given positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices (may not be of same dimension). The solution, $X$, has to be a *real* matrix of appropriate dimension such that the dimensions in left and right hand sides match. Also it is nice if we can show optimality of such solutions

Is there a general method for solving such inequalities? Advanced thanks for any help, suggestion, references, and etc..

Comment: The problem is not always solvable, such as when $Q$ has more negative eigenvalues than $P$, or when $P\ne0$ is purely imaginary but $Q\ne0$ is a real matrix with a zero diagonal. Anyway, you can always reformulate the problem so that $P$ and $Q$ become Hermitian matrices of the same sizes.

Comment: @user1551 I understand incompleteness in my question. I have modified it as $P$ and $Q $ to be positive semidefinite. For time, I can also assume both of them are strictly positive, but may have imaginary part. Is it then possible to solve it?

Comment: If $Q$ is positive semidefinite, you can just pick $X=0$.

Comment: @user1551 Actually I prefer a nontrivial solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose both $P$ and $Q$ are positive semidefinite.

If $Q\succeq YPY^T$ for some real $Y$, then $(I-QQ^+)YP=0$, i.e. $\left[P\otimes(I-QQ^+)\right]\operatorname{vec}(Y)=0$. Hence
$$
\pmatrix{\Re\left[P\otimes(I-QQ^+)\right]\\ \Im \left[P\otimes(I-QQ^+)\right]} \operatorname{vec}(Y)=0.\tag{1}
$$
Equation $(1)$ suggests that there usually isn't any non-trivial solution.

Since $Q$ is positive definite on its column space, given any real solution $Y$ to $(1)$, $X:=rY$ will be a real solution to $Q\succeq XPX^T$ when $r>0$ is sufficiently small. The usual argument shows that the maximum feasible value of $r$ is $\dfrac1{\sqrt{\rho(Q^+YPY^T)}}$.